# HTML is dominant in code sections

Tags: support, syntax-highlighting

I noticed that if a code section that's clearly C# contains some HTML or XML in a comment, it will be rendered as 100% HTML. Example [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8121496/how-to-write-boolean-attribute-specified-not-specified-with-xmlwriter/8121914#8121914).

Example that would highlight wrongly on SO:

```
string s = "hello world";
var i = s.Length();  // comment with <html><img></html>
```

SO shows the part `<html><img></html>` with HTML syntax highlighting both during editing  and after committing. I noticed that on Meta, this snippet isn't highlighted at all. So, potentially this issue only occurs on SO.

Edit: the referenced question has been edited, so the original effect is not visible anymore.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you post code written in language that does not appear as part of the question tags, you have to "manually" tell the code highlighter what is this language.

This is done by adding such line above the code, with one blank line below it:

```
<!-- language: lang-cs -->
```

This will tell the highlighter to treat it as `C#` code for example.

I have edited your answer as well. :)

For the record, the highlighter tried to parse the code as XML which appears as question tag.

Comment: Ah, thanks, looks much better now. I actually experimented with `<!-- language: c# -->` but apparently didn't get it right. So, it is true then, SO no longer looks at the code snippet and guesses, but now looks at the question tags only.

Comment: @Abel It never looked at the code snippet. Until tags were considered for the hoghlighting, we just used prettify's default "kinda works with any code" highlighter.